# Network Interfaces list, abstract type or interface

Tags: c#, winforms, network-interface

I have program which list HDD drives and Network interfaces like in this picture:
[image: Network interfaces list]

If I click on HDD name I can see drive type in text box. This is working fine.
However if I try this code on network interface its not working. It gave error CS0144: Cannot create an instance of the abstract type or interface 'NetworkInterface'

Here is code:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            textBox1.Text = "";
            DriveInfo[] Drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            foreach (DriveInfo drv in Drives)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(drv.Name);
            }
        }
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String strDrive = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;
            DriveInfo drive = new DriveInfo(strDrive);

            textBox1.Text = drive.DriveType.ToString();
        }
```

And here is not working network interfaces:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            textBox2.Text = "";
            NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(adapter.Name);
            }
        }

        private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String strInterface = (string)listBox2.SelectedItem;
            NetworkInterface adapter = new NetworkInterface(strInterface);
            textBox2.Text = adapter.Description.ToString();
        }
```

This line is wrong: NetworkInterface adapter = new NetworkInterface(strInterface);

Comment: GuruStron already gave a good answer. I'd like to provide some intuition on *why* those two cases are treated differently. Ponder on the names of the classes for a second. `DriveInfo` is a utility class to provide information about a drive. If you need information about the same drive twice (at different times), it makes sense to create a new "Info" instance each time. The other class is called `NetworkInterface`. A network interface is something that is already present on your PC. You don't want to create a new network interface, you want information about an *existing* network interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`NetworkInterface` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface?view=net-7.0):

> You do not create instances of this class; the `GetAllNetworkInterfaces` method returns an array that contains one instance of this class for each network interface on the local computer.

So you can call `GetAllNetworkInterfaces` again and filter the results:

```cs
var adapter = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    .FirstOrDefault(ni => ni.Name == strInterface);
// if not null ...
```

Or store results of previous call in some field/property and use those for search. Or just use the result array as datasource for `listBox2` itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the `NetworkInterface` instances directly in the list box items:

```
listBox2.Items.Add(adapter);
```

And set `listBox2.DisplayMember = nameof(NetworkInterface.Name)` to make the list box display their names.

Then you can access the selected adapter as:

```
var adapter = (NetworkInterface)listBox2.SelectedItem;;
```

Comment: Good idea. For consistency, I'd do the same for the drive list. This also prevents issues when a drive is changed (e.g. a USB stick is dismounted) between populating the list box and clicking an item.